# Кавычки в выводе

Tags: php, html, html5

Есть такой код:

```
<input name="name" value="<?= $name ?>">
```

проблема заключается в том, что при выводе имени с "" данные выводятся некорректно, как поступить в данной ситуации, $name может быть любой по составу

Comment: А если написать так? <?php echo $name; ?>

Comment: Тоже самое, уже пробовал. Тут скорее всего дело в экранировании

Comment: Можно конечно написать сумашедшую функцию разложения строки, экранирования, а после сложения, но мне кажется должен быть способ намного проще решить данную задачу

Comment: Используйте htmlspecialchars почти для любого вывода в html

Answer (score 6):

Используйте [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
<input name="name" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($name);?>">
```

Функция заменит кавычки на `&quot`. При выводе в разметке всё сохранится. Прикладываю разметку в качестве доказательства.

```html
<input name="name" value="Раз два &quot;три&quot;">
```

Comment: уже пробовал, не сработало

Comment: @Дмитрий что значит «не сработало»?

Comment: как я писал выше $name будет разной (в цикле), ваш вариант подойдет для частного случая

Comment: @Дмитрий это совершенно никак не мешает htmlspecialchars'у работать

Comment: @Дмитрий в каком случае, например, не поможет? Функция помогает выводить символы, которые зарезервированы в html, не ломая разметку. Она создана именно для этого

Comment: У меня по умолчанию библиотека redbeans, при обращении к данным htmlspecialchars уже есть(насколько я помню), там не совсем просто $name как я писал выше, там объект

Comment: @Дмитрий если бы библиотека применила `htmlspecialchars`, проблемы бы не возникло. Смотрите разметку в ответе

Comment: Это единственный корректный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Была у меня похожая проблема. Выводилось все, что до кавычек. Решил тем, что перевел поле VARCHAR в поле TEXT

Comment: К сожелению у меня оно уже в text, просто не обозначил выше, если я вас правильно понял type="text"

Comment: Там вариантов много, но суть была в том, что надо формат вывода сделать текст, а где это уже Вам там виднее.